# decltype filtering for container as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, decltype

I'm trying to write a generic function, that will return a size of any container, that has `size()` method and `size_type` definition. So far I tried two approaches and neither is compiling:

1.

```
template <typename Cont>
auto len(Cont const& cont) -> decltype(std::declval<Cont&>().size(), Cont::size_type)
{
    return cont.size();
}
```

2.

```
template <typename T, template <typename U, typename = std::allocator<U>> typename Cont>
auto len(Cont<T> const& cont) -> decltype(std::declval<Cont<T>&>().size(), Cont<T>::size_type)
{
    return cont.size();
}
```

Trying to test it:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
auto sz = len(vec);
```

Obviously, when I delete the trailing `decltype()`, everything ticks as expected. I know, that this can be achieved with `std::enable_if` as well, but for thew educational sake I have to figure this one. Please explain what I'm missing

P.S. For anyone who is going to mark the question as duplicate, I'm not asking "Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?", since by the time I'm writing the question, I haven't yet figured out, that this is what I'm missing

Comment: Btw, there is `std::size()`...

Comment: yeah, I know. The point is, that's not the only function I'm going to implement, so I had to get the pattern correctly.

Comment: The `std::declval` is a bit superfluous since you have access to `cont`, you can just write `decltype(cont.size(), typename Cont::size_type)`.

Comment: @Holt you're absolutely right, I noticed this later as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `typename` and a couple of parentheses

```
decltype(std::declval<Cont&>().size(), typename Cont::size_type{} )
// ....................................^^^^^^^^................^^
```

`typename` is needed to say that `size_type` is a type, inside `Cont`.

About the parentheses... take in count that `decltype()` return the type of an object. If you simply write

```
decltype( typename Cont::size_type )
```

you ask to detect a type from a type and `decltype()` doesn't work this way; you have to contruct an object of type `Cont::size_type` (so the parentheses) so that `decltype()` can detect the type.

Comment: Oh gosh, such a silly pitfall with a **typename** for the type :). Thanks a lot! It was just a first time I figured out a decltype could be used this way.